# Improve request cancelling in RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I'm starting using RxAndroid in my existing application. I've started with a quite simple activity where I have a search field and I contact an API using Retrofit when the text changes. I also want to cancel the current unfinished request if there's one before starting a new one. Here is what I have so far:

```
private Subscription currentRequestSubscription = null;

// Create stream of filtered queries
Observable<String> queryObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(searchView)
            .startWith("")
            .debounce(DELAY_BEFORE_REQUEST, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(new Func1<CharSequence, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return charSequence.toString();
                }
            })



// Make search request and update UI
queryObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String query) {
                if (currentRequestSubscription != null) {
                    currentRequestSubscription.unsubscribe();
                }

                currentRequestSubscription = createAPIRequestObservable(query)
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(... update UI with results ...);
            }
        });
```

I feel like storing the subscription is not really reactive programming compliant. How could I do this in a more standard way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to create a new subscription each time in this case, `switchMap` can take care of unsubscribing from the old observable when a new comes in. Something like this:

```java
currentRequestSubscription = RxTextView.textChanges(searchView)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .startWith("")
        .debounce(DELAY_BEFORE_REQUEST, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map(CharSequence::toString)
        .switchMap(text -> createAPIRequestObservable(text).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(/*... update UI with results ...*/);
```

Also good [example](https://medium.com/@diolor/improving-ux-with-rxjava-4440a13b157f#.ga5mdxu1j).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This causes a crash, if the API request takes a LONG time (low connection) and before it completes, the new one is triggered. I have still java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted.